# Next.js - axios in getInitialProps returns 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, next.js

Why does `getInitialProps` cause axios to throw an exception? When I call my service method anywhere else it works fine.

```
export default function JobIndex({ jobPosts }: JobIndexProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {jobPosts.map(jobPost => {
          return <li>{jobPost.title}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

JobIndex.getInitialProps = async (context): Promise<JobIndexInitialProps> => {
  const jobPosts = await JobPostService.list({ page: 1, perPage: 3 });
  return { jobPosts };
}
```

And this is my service class:

```
export class JobPostService {
  static async list(request: JobPostListRequest): Promise<JobPostListItem[]> {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/job-posts', { params: request });
    return response.data as JobPostListItem[];
  }
}
```

This the stack trace:

```
Server Error
Error: Request failed with status code 404

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Call Stack

createError
file: .../node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js (16:15)

settle
file: .../node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js (17:12)

IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
file: .../node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js (244:11)

IncomingMessage.emit
events.js (327:22)

endReadableNT
_stream_readable.js (1327:12)

processTicksAndRejections
internal/process/task_queues.js (80:21)
```

Comment: You need the full url when you do `axios.get('/api/job-posts'` on the server, a relative url won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on HMR's comment, I ended up modifying my service method to include the absolute url with my base url as an environment variable.

```
export class JobPostService {
  static async list(request: JobPostListRequest): Promise<JobPostListItem[]> {
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/job-posts`, { params: request });
    return response.data as JobPostListItem[];
  }
}
```